# Post nested resource and return new location Uri

Tags: asp.net, rest, api, asp.net-web-api2

I created an apicontroller that offers a Post method to create a new nested resource (in this example: customer > mediaFile):

```
[Route("api/Customer/{customerId}/MediaFile", Name = "CreateMediaFileForCustomer")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(MediaFile))]
public IHttpActionResult Post(long customerId, [FromBody]MediaFile mediaFile)
{
    ...

    return CreatedAtRoute("CreateMediaFileForCustomer", new { id = mediaFile.Id }, mediaFile);
}
```

I expected the CreatedAtRoute method to return a location header that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:51656/api/Customer/1/MediaFile/37
```

But instead I got this:

```
http://localhost:51656/api/Customer/1/MediaFile?id=37
```

After struggling quite a bit I came up with a "solution" that somehow feels like a cheesy approach:

```
[Route("api/Customer/{customerId}/MediaFile/{generatedMediaFileId:long?}", Name = "CreateMediaFileForCustomer")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(MediaFile))]
public IHttpActionResult Post(long customerId, [FromBody]MediaFile mediaFile)
{
    ...

    return CreatedAtRoute("CreateMediaFileForCustomer", new { generatedMediaFileId = mediaFile.Id }, mediaFile);
}
```

So like this I have an optional resource id that I only need to then set the location header correctly. Is this the way it is meant to work? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "CreatedAtRoute" location header should return a URL to where you can see the newly created resource. You are using the same route name as your POST method. So I would expect to see something like this:

```
[HttpGet()]
[Route("api/Customer/{customerId}/MediaFile/{id}", Name="GetMediaFileForCustomer")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(long customerId, long id)
{
    ....
}
```

And your `CreatedAtRoute` would be:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetMediaFileForCustomer", new { customerId = customerId, id = mediaFile.Id }, mediaFile);
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much Craig! Now I finally get it.